# Dock disappears on main display when focus on 2nd display's full screen app

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen, ventura

Main display (the one with the Menu Bar set to it in System Settings) is in normal desktop mode. Dock is visible.

2nd display has an application open in full screen mode.

The moment I put my focus on the full screen app in the 2nd screen, the dock in the main screen disappears.

I never observed that behavior before upgrading to macOS Ventura last week. If anyone knows how to fix that behavior to what it was before, I'd appreciate. Or should that be considered a bug?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does the Dock move to the other screen? With "Displays have separate Spaces' switched on in Mission Control prefs [which you must have to use a fullscreen app without it just blanking the other screen] then this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin It never happened to me before, and now in 13.0.1 (latest update), it's actually fixed. The Dock moves only if I push the mouse cursor down on another screen, not if I simply focus a full screen application on a secondary screen. That's the behavior I have since full screen apps exist and I have again with the latest patch.

Comment: Even weirder. I thought it was fixed with the OS update, but nope. And this morning, I see it being actually not even a "stable" bug. Seems to be mainly when using iTerm. This time, I de-full-screen-ed the app and it kept making the Dock disappear when I switched focus back to iTerm (not full screen). Doing again full-screen / not full screen "fixed" it. Random issue. We love those.

Comment: Ah, yes. Nothing beats trying to report a bug with no clear repro method :\ I do wish you luck :)